# Bluefruit LE connect signin issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ipad, bluetooth

I dowloaded the Bluefruit LE Connect Xcode form Adafruit (https://github.com/adafruit/Bluefruit_LE_Connect).

However when I want to run the program on mu iPad, I have two issues :
No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier “com.linox.bluefruitconnect” were found.

And when I click on fix it I have this :
The 'iCloud' feature is only available to users enrolled in Apple Developer Program. Please visit 
https://developer.apple.com/programs/ to enroll.
There was an error while interacting with the Developer Portal (9999, 4100).

At first I turned off the icloud capabilities of the project, but now, i cannot check it anymore as it has disappeared from my target capabilities menu.

Any help please ?

Note : I don't have a developper account as I only need to use the app on my iPad without iCloud (I just need the BLE)
the programs works on the simulators, but issues on the ipad.

Comment: you need a developer account

Comment: even if I don't need all the iCloud stuff ?? Is there a way to recode the app in a new project to use it's bluetooth capabilities ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. You need to register your development device into a provisioning profile as stated in the xcode output. TL;DR; about provisioning profile: it lists the allowed devices for a developer account. To do that, a dec account is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Right click your .xcodeproj and select Show Package Contents.  Open the project.pbxproj file in a text editor.  Search for com.apple.iCloud and set enabled = 0.

FYI:  OP, you have a developer account but not a paid developer account.  Other commenters, Apple now allows code signing and sideloading without a paid developer account, just not with certain features like iCloud.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I now have an issue with containers...when trying to delete them from profuct > icloud > delete, xcode just freeze each time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this has changed. So look for 
    com.apple.Push = {
       enabled = 1;
    }

and set enabled = 0;